# How to fix the notification in the Android to cover all API levels

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I like to cover my notification for all API levels.
To use `TaskStackBuilde`, I need API level minimum 16. I don't want to set `minSdkVersion` to   16 as I aim my app for lower API levels. So how I code is detect the API level and if above 16, I follow this format. And if lower Sdk, I follow that format. I want to be as follow

```
           int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
           if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
                // Do something for JELLY_BEAN and above versions
               TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
               // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
               stackBuilder.addParentStack(DetailMapView.class);
               // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
               stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
               PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                          stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                          0,
                          PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                          );
               mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            } else{
                // do something for phones running an SDK before JELLY_BEAN
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailMapView.class);
                PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(activity);
            }
```

But the code has error at `TaskStackBuilde` as my minSdk is 8. I don't want to change to 16 as I want to use my app for lower API level. How can I fix it? Any sample code avaliable for this?
Thanks

Comment: [`TaskStackBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html) is also part of the suppport library (v4) these days - have you looked at that?

Comment: You mean shouldn't have error? I got the error of I need min API level 16.

Comment: it means you can use the support library for your code to work on lower APIs

Comment: If you haven't heard about the support libraries before, [you'd better have a read](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html). Amongst other things, it makes functionality introduced with newer platforms available to older platforms. That includes the `TaskStackBuilder`. If you refer to the class that is part of the support library, you should be able to use its features on API level **4** and up.

Answer (score 0):

In order to close this issue. You can just use

```
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
```

instead of 
<del>import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;</del> to